# nimbus framework nipagingscrollview in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nimbus-ios

i am using the nimbus framework in my app to do a scroll view of pictures. i know they have a picture scroll view in the options but its not working for me.
the nipagingscrollview works perfect. the only problem is im having trouble making pinch to zoom on my pictures work.
according to apple references, all you need to do to handle pinch to zoom is be to adopt the scrollviewdelegate and return the view in the

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

my problem is i cant return the image view property because i am using a custom view that adopts the nipagingscrollview for each of the views in the scrolling view and when i try the

```
self.pagingscrollview.centerpageview
```

it says that pagingscroll view doesnt have a image view property which is true because he doesnt recognize that it is my custom view.

your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this : `YourCustomImageView *imageView = (YourCustomImageView *)self.pagingscrollview.centerpageview` to get your view.